# Can't use settextstyle( ) in graphics.h

Tags: c, ubuntu, bgi

I'm trying to use `settextstyle( )` function in my c code but it's not working. I'm using Ubuntu 20.4 and gcc compiler.
Here's my code

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int gd = DETECT,gm;
   initgraph(&gd,&gm,NULL);
  

   settextstyle(6, 1, 3);
   outtextxy(25, 25, "OUT TEXT XY");

   getchar();
   closegraph();
   return 0;
}
```

for compiling I'm using
`gcc test.c -lgraph`

and the error I'm getting is

```
test.c:11:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘settextstyle’; did you mean ‘setlinestyle’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   11 |    settextstyle(6, 1, 3);
      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |    setlinestyle
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccMWOEdk.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `settextstyle'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Hope you guys can help me

Comment: Why are you attempting MS DOS graphics in Ubuntu? Is it some sort of archaeology/retrocomputing project?

Comment: It's a college assignment

Comment: Why are you studying to become a MS DOS graphics programmer? There ain't a lot of jobs for those anywhere in the world.

Comment: Okay. Well the compiler can't find the functions. Presumably because you are using Linux and not MS DOS. In case you are running some manner of emulator, it isn't working or BGI wasn't installed correctly.

Comment: Yeah I'm using linux and libgraph for graphics.h and I just checked the lib and there is no function named settextstyle, btw thanks for your response.